# Sage Pay SERVER Protocol - Adding custom parameters to the Transaction Registration Request

Tags: opayo

Is there a way to pass custom parameters when making a Transaction registration request using the Sage Pay SERVER protocol?

I want to be able to pass a custom value to the request that can be retrieved when responding to the Notification POST.

I am currently doing this by appending values to the querystring for the **NextURL** parameter when registering the transaction.  However I would like to know if there is a better way of handling this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spoke with Sage Pay and they informed me that passing custom parameters in the Transaction Registration POST is not supported. So I ended up storing the values in the database along with the payment so that they could be retrieved when responding to the Notification POST.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the vendordata field to store your custom value on transaction registration, then extract it via the reporting API (getTransactionDetail) when you need it I guess...

It's really easier to use a query string, though.

Comment: I am using the hosted payment solution. The documentation for the Server protocol doesn't mention a 'vendordata' field. Sage told me that custom parameters were not supported, so I decided to store the additional information in the database and retrieve it when responding to the Notification POST.

Comment: Fair enough. FYI - vendordata is on page 49 of the Server doc.

Comment: So it is.  I had an old version of the documentation.  I don't really want this information to be permanently stored against the transaction though, and 200 chars may not be sufficient.  I think I'll stick with my solution.